# gnome-terminal: how do you set working-directory?

Tags: gnome-terminal

This has been bugging me for years. The terminal starts up in`~/Desktop` (up to 20.04, anyway), which is completely useless. How do I fix this? What I know so far:

1. It doesn't start in the current directory, so any changes to `.bashrc`/etc won't help. `~/Desktop` behaves almost as if it's compiled into the app
2. There are no `dconf` settings (`/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles`) related to setting `working-directory`
3. You can't set in the profile for a given terminal
4. You can't set it by editing the `Exec` string in `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` - it doesn't work

If you already have a terminal open, then this *does* work:

```
$ gnome-terminal --working-directory=$HOME
```

But if you change any/all of the `Exec` strings in `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop`, it makes no difference:

`Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory=$HOME`

This last one is known to work in RHEL.

**Update:**

1. A desktop icon starts up in my home directory, when there is *no* `working-directory` in the `Exec` setting
2. CTL-ALT-t starts up in my home dir, presumably using the global settings in `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop`
3. Desktop right-click always starts up in `~/Desktop`, per vanadium's comment
4. `update-alternatives` output is

   $ update-alternatives --display x-terminal-emulator
   x-terminal-emulator - auto mode
   link best version is /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
   link currently points to /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
   link x-terminal-emulator is /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
   slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/x-terminal-emulator.1.gz
   /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper - priority 40
   slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gnome-terminal.1.gz

Comment: See my answer, but still it would be good to specify in detail how you start up the terminal (right-click on desktop? From an icon on the desktop? Using a shortcut key?). That it opens in the Desktop directory by default is rather unusual and will depend on how you start it up. Right-click on the desktop opens it in that folder by design.

Comment: @vanadium: interesting - right-click, `Open in terminal`, fails. CTL-ALT-T, works! I always use a panel icon in RHEL - I'll give that a go.

Comment: What  gives `update-alternatives --display x-terminal-emulator` can you add this to your question please?

Comment: Maybe a problem  in the  wrapper skript? gnome-terminal is "called"  over this perlsktrpt and get the option from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click on the desktop, the menu you'll get is the *desktop*'s menu. It'll have entries such as "New Folder" creating a new folder on the desktop. It also has an entry called "Open in Terminal" (notice the word "in"!), which opens the terminal in the Desktop directory, or actually using the menu entry's logic I should rather say it opens the Desktop directory in a terminal.

I personally agree with you in that I find this a pretty useless feature, so I never use this menu entry. I personally use either the global shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, or click on the icon in the dock / launcher (whatever it's called), this latter method having the advantage that I can start up the terminal the *same* way as I'd start up my other favorite and frequently used applications.

Note that it has nothing to do with GNOME Terminal, it's all about the Desktop. If you change your preferred terminal to something else, the desktop's "Open in Terminal" menu will open that one in that folder. No wonder that you didn't find any options about the working directory in GNOME Terminal's settings, indeed there aren't any, it's absolutely not GNOME Terminal's decision to open in that folder.

My personal recommendation is to avoid using that menu entry which, by questionable design, intends to open a terminal in the Desktop directory. That being said, finding the *right* `.desktop` file and adding the `--working-directory` flag to `gnome-terminal` should also work, as per vanadium's comments. Yet another possibility is to fix up the directory from `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 3):

It *will* work if you explicitly spell out the directory instead of specifying $HOME. Reason: desktop launchers do not support bash variables or bash expansions.

Comment: I replaced `$HOME` with `/home/myname` in all 3 occurrences of the `Exec` setting in `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop`, but unfortunately it made no difference, even after a logout. Same result when running direct on a laptop or over vnc. But surely this can't be right, because there's then no way to specify per-user directories?

Comment: Yes, your comment was enough - CTL-ALT-T does the job, and my new icon works as well, so no problem left. You may well be right about the explicit path, but I think you may have found the magic *desktop* `.desktop` file, rather than the `/usr/share/applications` version, so +1 for effort :)

Comment: Because it doesn't actually work (for me, anyway) on right-click, which is what I was (previously) doing: using a full path doesn't help (see my first comment). Maybe it's working for you because you're using a different `.desktop` file, which is what I was trying to say in the last comment. I'm inclined to believe that the terminal produced by right-click on the desktop is *hard-wired* to start up in `~/Desktop`,  as per @egmont's reply, and stuff I've seen on the net about KDE's approach to this.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I do not really grasp what the question really is about.