# Opening terminal by default in home directory does not work

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. The terminal that it opens from desktop context menu is the gnome-terminal. By default it opens it on the ~/Desktop directory. I want to modify the default directory **without** changing .bashrc. I've encountered a suggestion to add --working-directory=$HOME to the "Exec" entry of /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop. It does not work - the terminal still opens on "~/Desktop".

Any ideas?

Freddy

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can’t edit .bashrc?

Comment: This should provide useful information: https://askubuntu.com/q/1435378/398785

Comment: From what I know - modifying directory in .bashrc has other side effects.

Comment: @egmont thanks, now I understand it better. Looks like clicking “Open in Terminal” on the desktop opens the terminal in the desktop directory always. Makes sense - though it’s not what I wanted…

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal first then from the hamburger buttons (3 lines just after the search icon) select preferences. Head to your profile and then go to "command" header.Modify "preserve working directory". You have to choose either "Always" or "Shell only"